# Why would a plane have these lights on the bottom?

Tags: aircraft-design, aircraft-lighting

I'm trying to convince someone this is not a UFO but probably just not a commercial plane. What would be the reasons to have the colors of the plane lights like this?

The person is claiming because it was inaudible, seemed rather large, and had blinking lights that it is a UFO. Are there any reasons for this as well?

Coordinates: 36.841900,-87.673600 Kentucky
Time: July 4, 2020, 12:29am

[image]

Comment: Tell us the time and place, and we can likely find the exact aircraft.

Comment: @Camille Goudeseune This was in Tennessee. I am attempting to get the exact location and time this occurred. I'll report back once I have that. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Aviation SE, David!  FYI, on a Q&A site like this, when you have more info, it's good to edit your original question and put the info there, instead of tacking on more comments.  We look forward to solving the mystery...

Comment: @Camille Goudeseune The coordinates are  38.842, -87.674. Time: July 4, 2020, 12:29am.

Comment: If you cannot identify an object, and the object is flying, then it is, (by definition) an unidentified flying object.  That is not the same thing as confirming (or even suggesting) that it is a spacecraft from another galaxy.  ;)

Comment: It is likely not unidentified, but not identified by him lol.

Comment: Any additional information such as movement, duration, etc.?  July 4th makes it seem very likely that they were distant Chinese floating lanterns like these:  https://www.justartifacts.net/flskyla.html

Comment: @MichaelHall It was low to the ground, seemed fairly large (apparently), and made no noise. It seemed to flash as well and maintained a triangular position.

Comment: @CamilleGoudeseune My apologies for not correctly using the @ feature. I have updated the post to include the coordinates and time.

Comment: Those ETs use the same navigation lights than on Earth, red on left, green on right, and red blinking anticollision on the belly or the tail ([rotated / annotated picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8qpkV.png)). They are not as smart as ET experts think, they need to copy our barely emerging civilization (maybe we can sue them for intellectual property laws infringement to give them a taste of who they will be dealing with).

Comment: @mins thanks so much for your reply! That explains a lot.